# Vulnerability error in loader-utils in Angular 12

Tags: angular, webpack

When I run security scan in my `angular 12` application, I'm getting vulnerability error with `loader-utils:2.0.0`. I understand, the `loader utils` is used by the `angular devkit`. Is there any way to upgrade `loader-utils` from `2.0.0` to `3.*.*` without upgrading `angular` ?

I'm getting the below error now.

```
Prototype pollution vulnerability in function parseQuery in parseQuery.js in webpack loader-utils prior to version 2.0.3 via the name variable in parseQuery.js.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loader-utils` is fixed dependency, so you'll have to upgrade.

BUT:

As `@angular-devkit/build-angular` is only used in the building stages, `loader-utils` will not be included in the built artifact.

There is no security issue for your app.